# Vue page cannot open after refreshing the page

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3

I added the routes dynamically to the router and I can visit all pages with router-view. However, when I try to refresh the page I cannot visit the page again although the URL is the same. It is `http://localhost:8081/me`.

```
this.$router.addRoute("Main", {
              path: '/me',
              name: 'Me',
              component: () => import(`@/components/Me.vue`)
            });
```

As I said, I can normally visit the page "Me", but when I refresh it, I cannot see its content anymore with the warning:

**[Vue Router warn]: No match found for location with path "/me"**

I tried to create router with `createWebHistory("/")` after reading [the cause of the error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65109585/vue-router-vue-3-createwebhistory-no-match-found-for-location-with-path)  but nothing seems to change.  I will appreciate any help.

Comment: Where do you add the route?

Comment: Ideally router creation and route declaration is one time bootstrapping activity. You should not need to use `addRoute` method, expect in rare scenarios. That could be the reason that when you refresh this particular piece of code is not being executed causing *No Match* error. Declare all routes upfront when initializing the router.

Comment: @shob I create the routers in router/index.js but I add new routers in components/common/LeftMenu.vue.

Comment: @HarshalPatil I declare routes while initializing the router, but I also want to add new routes. So do you think I cannot use another component to add more routes? But I want to add new routes dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two reasons why this would happen.

#### First serving SPA application from the server.

Make sure that your back-end is set to serve `index.html` file for all routes since back-end server is unaware of the routes set by client-side router. Something like [express-history-api-fallback-middleware](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-history-api-fallback) can help is using Node.js/Express.js.

#### Second problem is that of using `addRoute`.

As you described, the problem could be that Vue router is taking routing decision before your code in `components/common/LeftMenu.vue` is getting executed which is responsible for calling `addRoute()`. Ensure that this code is called before routing decision is being made. Best way would be to move this logic in top-level application component. And, if you can move that to top-level components, that means you can try to declare all routes while defining the router.

Why that should be done?

Using `addRoute` is not necessarily an anti-pattern but having to rely on `addRoute` is often code smell. You would really need it in extremely rare scenarios. Routing is a high-level architectural concern for your application and thus better to be declared upfront somewhere at top-level module even before application is getting initialized. Low level components should not attempt to manipulate routing data structure (violation of DIP principles).

One scenario where you might be tempted to use `addRoute` is taking decision after some data manipulation by the component with addition of some API call. That seems legitimate need but then to address that there are better ways. Considering using **route guards** (guards support async resolution too!) and prevent user from entering the view till the guard is resolved successfully.

Comment: Thanks, router navigation guards solve the problem.

Comment: @selubamih did you solve the problem? Can you please provide the solution, I'm facing same issue here and I don't know how to tackle it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69112290/instruct-vue-router-to-re-render-correct-page-when-refresh