# Instruct vue-router to re-render correct page when refresh

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3

My application is built by vuejs + rails, it has these router components:

```
 {
    path: '/',
    name: 'home',
    component: Home,
    children: [
      {
        path: '/',
        name: 'welcome',
        component: Welcome,
      },
      {
        path: '/classes/:id',
        name: 'class',
        component: Class,
      },
      {
        path: '/classes/:id/members',
        name: 'member',
        component: Member,
      },
      {
        path: '/account',
        name: 'account',
        component: Account,
      },
      ...
    ]
  },
```

The router-link parts work fine when I navigate the link, but when I'm standing in `/classes/1 path` and refresh the url, it result a not found error:

`No route matches [GET] "/classes/1"`

I understand that when I refresh, I make a new request to the server, so I added this
routing in rails router:

```
get '/*path', to: 'home#index'
```

So instead of raising an error, it render home page successful but that is not what I want.
I want it still keep or reload the current page where I 'm in.
If I'm in `/classes/1` and hit refresh, it should keep/refresh `/classes/1` page.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: Rails should route only to the home page. Vue-router will handle things from there. You're saying that client side navigation to /classes/1 -> refresh, redirects you back to `/`?

Comment: Yes, it is, so how can I instruct vue-router to render the page properly?

Comment: Last clarification: Is it updating the URL to `/` or staying as `/classes/1` but showing the content on `/`?

Comment: If I use router rails to redirect everything to `home#index` page, it updating URL to `/`,  and if i don't (remove `get '/*path', to: 'home#index'`), it staying as /classes/1 and results a Routing Error `No route matches [GET] "/classes/1"`. I want it stays as `/classes/1` and render Class component.

Answer (score 0):

Here are modified versions of key parts of an app I did at work.

```ruby
# config/routes.rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root('application#index')

  # I use a scope because in the real app I also have other routes such as
  # browserconfig.xml and site.webmanifest which are both procedurally
  # generated.
  scope('/', format: false) do
    # Catch all for HTML 5 history routing. This must be the last route.
    get('*path', to: 'application#index')
  end
  # equivalent, if scope is unnecessary
  # get('/*path', to: 'application#index', format: false)
end
```

```ruby
# app/controllers/application_controller.rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  def index
    # Avoid having an empty view file.
    render(inline: '', layout: 'application')
  end
end
```

```slim
/ app/views/layouts/application.html.slim
doctype html
html
  head
    / ...

  body
    main

    / Webpacker 4.3.0
    = javascript_packs_with_chunks_tag('main', defer: true)
```

In my JS code, I mount a Vue instance on the `main` element. All client-side/Vue routes are handled through my Vue router. I have a JS directory tree structure as follows:

```
project_root/
|-- src/
    |-- api/ <- external REST API handling code
    |-- channels/ <- Action Cable stuff
    |-- components/ <- Vue SFC's and functional components
    |-- images/ <- image files
    |-- lib/ <- various local library code
    |-- mixins/ <- Vue component mixins
    |-- packs/ <- all files in here are picked up by Webpacker; these are the entry-points
        |-- main.mjs <- imports pages/main.mjs (my app has multiple packs and pages, and there's "some" logic behind this structure)
    |-- pages/
        |-- main.mjs <- does the heavy lifting of building the Vue instance
    |-- plugins/ <- Vue plugins
    |-- scss/ <- SCSS files
    |-- store/ <- Vuex stuff
    |-- vendor/ <- third-party vendor stuff, like poly-fills
    |-- main.mjs
```

```js
// src/pages/main.mjs
import '@/scss/main.scss';

// this should be first to ensure `vendors` loads first
import build from '@/main';

import VuexRouterSync from 'vuex-router-sync';
import App from '@/components/app.vue';
import router from '@/lib/router';
import store from '@/store';

build(
  App,
  {
    router,
    store,
  },
  (Vue) => {
    Vue.use(BootstrapVueUtils);

    VuexRouterSync.sync(store, router);
  },
);
```

```js
// src/main.mjs
import '@/vendor';
import isFunction from 'lodash-es/isFunction';
import Vue from 'vue';

export default function build(appComponent, config = {}, preInit = null) {
  // call Vue.use here for any plugins that are common to all packs/pages
  // Vue.use(Vuelidate);

  if (preInit == null && isFunction(config)) {
    preInit = config;
    config = {};
  }

  if (isFunction(preInit)) {
    preInit(Vue);
  }

  function init() {
    new Vue({
      beforeCreate() {
        Vue.$rootVm = this;
      },

      render(h) {
        return h(appComponent);
      },

      ...config,
    }).$mount('main');
  }

  if (document.readyState === 'loading') {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init);
  } else {
    init();
  }
}
```

```js
// src/lib/router.mjs
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import Folder from '@/components/folders/show.vue';
import Folders from '@/components/folders'; // index.vue
import Home from '@/components/home.vue';
import LogIn from '@/components/log-in.vue';
import NotFound from '@/components/not-found.vue';
import Settings from '@/components/settings'; // index.vue

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  saveScrollPosition: true,
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      redirect: '/folders',
      component: Home,
      children: [
        {
          name: 'folders',
          path: 'folders',
          component: Folders,
        },
        {
          name: 'folder',
          path: 'folders/:id',
          component: Folder,
        },
        {
          name: 'settings',
          path: 'settings',
          component: Settings,
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      name: 'log-in',
      path: '/log-in',
      component: LogIn,
    },
    // This isn't necessary, and I question it now. Has no effect on the functioning of the router.
    {
      name: 'not-found',
      path: '*',
      component: NotFound,
    }
  ],
});

// There's some additional code after this to setup event handling on the
// `router`, specifically `router.beforeEach` to check the logged-in status
// and if not logged in redirect to the log-in route.
```

This is a lot of code, but I wanted to try and cover everything from Rails router to Vue router, and also include some extra stuff that might help.

I did notice that you included the leading `/` in the children array of your `'home'` Vue route. That's unnecessary as it's implied based on the parent.

From the [Vue Router docs](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/nested-routes.html):

> Note that nested paths that start with / will be treated as a root path. This allows you to leverage the component nesting without having to use a nested URL.

So, while unnecessary, I don't think it's the cause of your issue.

The only thing I can think of, is to make absolutely certain the Rails catch-all route is the very last route. Rails routing matches from top-bottom in order of how the routes are specified in the `config/routes.rb` file.

Comment: I still don't know what is wrong in my setting up, almost are same with you. I put rails router catching at the last line `get '/*path', to: 'home#index', format: false` , except the leading `/`. I removed it but the app still can not reload the current page. It always renders  Welcome page.

Comment: For your example, this setting `get('*path', to: 'application#index')` will always redirect to your `application#index` page where you mounted the vue root app, so whenever I refresh I think it will render your vue root app component, it is `Home` component, I 'm wondering how vue can route to proper previous path, for example: `/settings` or `/folders/1`

Comment: The Vue router looks at the URL in the browser. If it's `example.com/`, then it renders the `Home` component. If it's `example.com/account`, then it will render the `Account` component. If it's `example.com/classes/1`, then it will render the `Class` component. That's why the `get('/*path', to: 'home#index')` is important, as that prevents any unknown routes in Rails, and allows the URL to remain intact.

Comment: If your Vue app is not located at the root of the domain/subdomain, then you'll need to update your Vue router paths; e.g., if app root is at `example.com/my-app/`, then the `home` Vue route path should be `/my-app/`, and `class` would be `/my-app/classes/:id`.

Comment: What do you mean of `allows the URL to remain intact`, so your URL does not change when you refresh? In my case, URL always become `/` root, not remain the refresh link (`/classes/1`)

Comment: I don't know why my URL is changed to `/`

Comment: I can navigate directly to `example.com/folders/1` by typing it in the address bar of my browser, and the `Folder` component will be rendered. Something you could try is use Vue Router's [navigation guards](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html) to add `console.log` statements to help trace how the routing is happening; e.g., `/* for the home route; Console is a custom util class */ beforeEnter(to, from, next) { Console.debug('route (/): beforeEnter'); next(); }`. In fact, in my project I have all of these in place, and only disable them for production builds.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236993/discussion-between-jordan-pickwell-and-tiktac).

Answer (score -2):

You have to redirect all requests to your index.html so vue-router can handle the request.

If you use apache => https://gist.github.com/Prezens/f99fd28124b5557eb16816229391afee

with nginx => https://stackoverflow.com/a/47656569/8613189

Comment: Can you please more clarify?

Comment: This is irrelevant to a Rails app since everything should go through the Rails router, assuming you want to be able to utilize the Rails session cookie.